# NVDA's elements list doesn't recognize the <nav> in a <header> if it's the first direct child

Tags: header, accessibility, nav, nvda

Has anyone experienced this, and if so, do you have an explanation and/or solution? Basically, if you have the following markup, the "Primary" nav won't be recognized in NVDA unless there's a non-nav element preceding it.

```
<header role="banner">
    <nav role="navigation" aria-label="Primary">...</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I remember from a recent audit that it was judged redundant to mark a single navigation inside headers or footers. I’ll try to find it…

Comment: What do you mean it’s not recognised? It doesn’t show in the navigation landmarks? Or when entering it it’s role is not announced?

Comment: Found it: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-nav-element:the-nav-element-2

Comment: Andy, yeah, it doesn't appear in the landmarks list as you would expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly valid HTML to nest a `<nav>` element within a `<heading>` element, and there are no sematic issues with doing so.

That said, NVDA doesn't appear to display elements in the "*Landmarks List*" if they are children of other landmark elements.

NVDA will see and announce your `<nav>` element within the `<header>`, but only if you manually step through the page content.

This means that if you nest a `<nav>` within a `<header>`, only the top-level element (in this case `<header>` would be visible in the "*Landmarks List*", and the child-element would not be accessible by cycling through landmarks with keyboard shortcuts.

If it were me, I would probably move the `<nav>` element outside the `<header>`, but neither way is technically wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. What's interesting is, if you place a <div>, <p>, or anything else before the <nav> NVDA will display the nav in the Landmarks List.

Comment: @36lpi -- thank you for clarifying the behavior you're describing. I was able to replicate the issue on my system. After some digging on NVDA's GitHub, I found a bug report for this issue: https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/12699  So, you're not doing anything wrong, and I don't think there's anything you can do to fix it other than just work around it. Good find!